# Lossing bytes when moving from char[] to const char*

Tags: c++

I have an array of characters that has the following bytes in it:

```
output[0]         = 0
output[1]         = 0
output[2]         = 4
output[3]         = -46
output[4]         = 0
output[5]         = 0
output[6]         = 0
output[7]         = 0
```

When I pass this array to the following function as the second paramater

```
this->refServer->Transmit(ConnectionId,output);

void Server::Transmit(int ConnectionIndex, const char* MessageToSend)
```

The array turns into a null. I'm guessing that array is trimmed when its converted to a const char* to the first null character, but I don't know how to prevent this without changing the out going bytes.

Comment: No, it is not "trimmed". The issue is somewhere else (trying to use the array in a string function? a different type?)

Comment: It's nothing to do with making it a `const char *`. You're using functions that expect a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from `char[]` to `const char*` is a no-op, it cannot be the reason.

In your case, the problem most likely is that `Server::Transmit` expects the buffer to be a null-terminated string. So it considers the first zero byte (which is the first element of the array) as the end of message. So you just cannot send a zero byte with this implementation.

You need either to change `Transmit` implementation so you can pass a length of message there, or to invent an escaping scheme for zero values (thus changing the outgoing bytes).